# golang find first element smaller or equal to given element using sort.Search

Tags: go

golang find first element smaller or equal to given element using `sort.Search()` if the array is sorted in ascending order.

Note: I do not want to sort the array in descending order to use the `sort.Search`

Answer (score 2):

In your “less” function, implement “more” instead. You may need to adjust the resulting index by 1.